# KeyError in the .append() function, when translating csv to json

Tags: python, json

Okay, so here is what Im trying to do.
I am trying to take a csv file and translate this into a Json so i can compare data sets.

However, for some reason I am unable to find, when i try and append the headings there is an error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

Here is my code

```
#Open file 
Open file
with open(filename, "r") as f:
        sampleReader = csv.DictReader(f)
        next(sampleReader)
        data = {"test":[]}
        for row in sampleReader:
            data["test"].append({"ACTIVITY DATE": row[0]})
        print(data)
```

Traceback:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-582fa1fa84a1> in <module>
      5         data = {"test":[]}
      6         for row in sampleReader:
----> 7             data["test"].append({"ACTIVITY DATE": row[0]})
      8         print(data)
      9 

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Please add the exact error and the full traceback if possible. There's no such thing as an "unknown Error".

Comment: Error has been added

Comment: It means the `row` **dictionary** returned by the `DictReader` has no entry with a key value of `0`.

Comment: Try printing `row` on the line before where the error happens, and you’ll see what you’re trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to specify a field by its column number (as you do with `row[0]`) rather than its column name, you should use `csv.reader` instead of `csv.DictReader`:

```
sampleReader = csv.reader(f)
```

If you would like to specify a field by its column name, you should not skip a row with `next(sampleReader)` since `csv.DictReader` already consumes the header row, and you should also use the desired column name as a key to retrieve the value of the field:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
        sampleReader = csv.DictReader(f)
        data = {"test":[]}
        for row in sampleReader:
            data["test"].append({"ACTIVITY DATE": row['activity date']})
        print(data)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify this? I do want to specify by name? the column name is "activity date"?

Comment: @ZaweeeZ Try printing `row`. Then you will quickly see why `row[0]` gives a `KeyError`.

Comment: @ZaweeeZ I've updated my answer accordingly then.